# Displaying a list of items that have a fundamentally different html representations

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Suppose I have a list of items that I want to show in html. It could for example be:

```
List<MyBusinessObject> item;
```

where MyBusinessObject is defined as such:

```
public class MyBusinessObject
{
    public string Value1{ get; set; };
    public string Value2{ get; set; };
    public string Value3{ get; set; };
    public CategoryEnum Category{ get; set; };
}
```

Suppose I want to display each MyBusinessObject with a fundamentally different html ( different tags and css classes for example ) depending on the Category.

How would you solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by fundamentally different? Different CSS classes, changing visibility of certain controls based upon `Category`? Do you use ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Comment: ASP.NET WEbForms. Fundamentally different Html. I edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose to add a [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a [`MultiView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227665%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the ItemTemplate. The repeater allows for adding a custom ItemTemplate and the MultiView provides an easy way to switch between different views. In the ItemDataBound event handler of the Repeater, you can set the correct view of the `MultiView`.

### Markup for the Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:MultiView ID="multiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View runat="server">
                <asp:Panel runat="server">
                    <h1>View 1 - 
                    <asp:Label runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category") %>' />
                    </h1>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' />
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View runat="server">
                <asp:Panel runat="server">
                    <h1>View 2 - 
                    <asp:Label runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category") %>' />
                    </h1>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' />
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var items = new List<MyDataItem>();
        items.Add(new MyDataItem() { Name = "Item1", Category = "Cat1" });
        items.Add(new MyDataItem() { Name = "Item2", Category = "Cat2" });
        items.Add(new MyDataItem() { Name = "Item3", Category = "Cat1" });
        items.Add(new MyDataItem() { Name = "Item4", Category = "Cat2" });
        items.Add(new MyDataItem() { Name = "Item5", Category = "Cat1" });
        rpt.DataSource = items;
        rpt.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
        || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var multiView = e.Item.FindControl("multiView") as MultiView;
        if (multiView != null)
            multiView.ActiveViewIndex = 
                ((MyDataItem)e.Item.DataItem).Category == "Cat1" ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

public class MyDataItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Suppose there are 5 categories. Would you think adding usercontrols for each type is ok? Then make a switch statement to decide ActiveViewIndex?

Comment: @Skúli: yes, UserControls are a good way to factor out the different layouts if they are more complex than in the sample. Otherwise, the view markup would bloat the ItemTemplate and make it less readable. A switch is an easy way to decide which view to take. Just don't forget to extend it when adding new categories.